# Parse Push Notification Internal tester's device doesn't register ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm about to release my first mobile application. I use parse for push notification. I create all certificate for push notification. Now in developer.apple.com my app's permission looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut1IR.png

I didn't create developer certificate because i've already tested it.

I sent this app to AppStore and i'll test it with my internal tester. But when they open the app and say yes to notification, tester's device doesn't add to Parse's database. What's wrong with this application?

Edit: I wrote the code with Swift 2

didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded, error) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken have you write code in this

Comment: which is provided by parse.com

Comment: what is your coding lang.? swift / obj-c?

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        ParseCrashReporting.enable()

        Parse.setApplicationId(“xxxxx”, clientKey: “xxxxxx”)


        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
        let defaultACL = PFACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

        let cu = PFUser.currentUser()
        println("current user - \(cu?.email)")
        PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var noPushPayload = false;
            if let options = launchOptions {
                noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }
        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
            let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }
}
```